# visual studio 2013 needs internet connection to load symbols

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created an application that needs to run on a standalone machine that has and cannot have any internet connection.

Everything was going well until I tried to run the app in visual studio 2013. I have found that I need to be connected to the internet when I first run the app in the IDE. The issue is that it seems to need to load symbols from application extensions. I have used a few extensions, xceed WPF toolkit, BrainboxesIO, Log4net, SnmpSharpNet. After the app runs once it doesnt need to happen again until I reboot my machine. How can I prevent the need for internet connectivity, firstly whilst developing in the IDE.

I have tried to deploy my app. I can create a setup project. But as soon as I use the configuration manager to go to release, I lose reference to the same extensions. If I create a .msi in debug the app runs, but again needs the internet when it first runs. I can then disconnect and it runs provided I don't reboot, which is obviously not what I need.

Anyone have any idea what I'm not doing right?

Comment: Err..can't you just copy the `.exe` file from the /bin/Debug/ or /bin/Release/ folder to that standalone machine, instead of trying to run your program through Visual Studio?

Comment: 1) These aren't extensions, they are the libraries used by your application. 2) VS tries to download symbols only if you tell it to. Just press cancel when it tries to download them or turn off symbol servers from `Debug | Options | Symbols". Also make sure you have checked `Enable Just My Code` in the General options

Comment: Deployment is a different matter, you should create a different question with sufficient information - *what* did you include in the deployment package? The project's output or only the `exe` file from the `Debug` directory?  The project output would include the referenced dlls